# femanager - how to send registration to special page (and not to just the active one)

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-extensions

I have a working installation of typo3 with extension femanager. If I use femanager from the page where a content element with this plugin is included, all works fine.

Now I want to use a field for registration on every(!) page, e. g. in the footer. I do this by including the existing content element into the fluidtemplate by typoscript. The field ist perfectly visible and works as expected if I use it on that page where the plugin is stored. This is because the plugin sends the data to the actual displayed page.

But in moste cases no femanager-plugin is stored at the actual page to handle the sent controller data.

How can I define a forced special target page to send the data to?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself but it's not the best way because there can be only one target page defined at all. Maybe you can play a little bit with constants and variables...

Use your own root paths for femanager templates:

```
plugin.tx_femanager.view.templateRootPaths.10 = path/to/my/version/of/femanager/Templates/
```

Add attribute `pageUid` to the f:form tag in 
`path/to/my/version/of/femanager/Templates/New/New.html` with the proper page uid:

```
        <f:form
                pageUid="142"
                name="user"
                object="{user}"
                action="create"
                enctype="multipart/form-data"
                additionalAttributes="{data-femanager-plugin:data.uid}"
                class="form-horizontal {f:if(condition:'{settings.new.validation._enable.client}',then:'feManagerValidation',else:'')}">
```